# removing a char from an array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, char

I've been trying to remove a specific character from an Array of Strings but continue to fail. The char is "$", I don't know what I'm doing wrong so hoping someone would be able to point to the right direction, my code:

```
for (int y = 0; y<possibleAnswers.length;y++) {
        display = possibleAnswers[y].replaceAll("$", "");
        System.out.println(display);
    }
```

possibleAnswers contains 4 Strings, one of the 4 has a "$", I want to remove it before displaying it.

When I run the above code, the "$" is displayed, any ideas?

Comment: You completely misunderstand the purpose of `replaceAll`. You should read documentation and discover, that `replaceAll` is the method for replacing the regular expression, not just the exact matching string. Here `replace` should be used.

Comment: In additon to what Dmitry Ginzburg said. In regular expressions, `$` has special meaning which is end of line. Means, You are replacing end of line character with blank.

Comment: Apologies, your answer is correct and I'm using it in my code now, that's the method I was looking for. I have not read the documentation, that's my fault.

Comment: Ashwani, I'm making a "who wants to be a millionare" game, that's why I have an array of four Strings, one has a $ sign indicating the correct answer. I wanted to remove it before displaying it, but before doing so, record the correct answer to compare with user input later on. What other options do I have? Should I use a different char? or is there a complete different and more efficient method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `replaceAll()` expects a "regular expression". The $ character has a specific meaning when used in a regular expression. Therefore you have two options:

1. Keep using `replaceAll()`; then you have to "escape the special character"; by using `replaceAll("\\$", "")`, or "[$]" as others have pointed out.
2. Use a different method, like `replace()` that doesn't expect a "regular expression pattern string".

Comment: For 1 could also do replaceAll ("[$]", "");

Comment: As I've already pointed out in the other answer, `replace(char, char)` is also suitable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char), but in this case you can't use, because there's no "empty" symbol.

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll()` accepts a regex, not just a character. When you say "$", you're not telling it to match the '$' character, but to match the ending position of the String or before a newline before the end of the String.

You need to **escape** the '$', so it knows to match just the character, and not treat it like it's special regex meaning.

Do this like: `possibleAnswers[y].replaceAll("\\$", "");`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
possibleAnswers[y].replaceAll("\\$", "");
```

escape the character because `$` is a special character in regular expression and since `replaceAll()` take regular expression the string you passed is unidentified.

You can also use `replace()` which take string

```
 possibleAnswers[y].replace("$", "");
```

Comment: And the better solution is just replacing `replaceAll` with `replace`, no need to escape then.

Comment: Your answer solves the issue at hand; but doesn't explain at all **why** this will work.

Comment: I used replace instead of replaceAll and it worked, thanks Dmitry, and singhakash's answer is correct also, thanks for the explanation, I didn't know I had to identify special characters differently. Why does special char works without // in replace method, but not replaceAll?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg But if the person doesn't pay attention, then he might turn to "replace(char, char)" - which only replaces once; not "all". So be careful when talking about "better" solutions.

Comment: @Jägermeister Nope. ["Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Comment: @almostabeginner Because "regular expressions" are special notion; basically a very powerful concept to describe "patterns". And the one method supports that specific notion, the other does not. Simply google "java regular expression".

Answer (score 1):

IN your code the `$` is `keyword` in `regex` for matching `end of line` i.e. $. SO you will have to `escape` it as below.

```
display = possibleAnswers[y].replaceAll("\\$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use possibleAnswers[y].replace("$", ""); to remove "$" from string.

Comment: As said before: your answer solves the issue at hand; but doesn't explain at all why this will work.

Comment: public String replace(CharSequence paramCharSequence1,
   CharSequence paramCharSequence2) {
  return Pattern
    .compile(paramCharSequence1.toString(), 16)
    .matcher(this)
    .replaceAll(
      Matcher.quoteReplacement(paramCharSequence2.toString()));
 }

Comment: Edit your answer if you want to improve it. And btw: just adding the code you put in your comment will not improve the quality of the answer. The point is: your answer is missing an **explanation**. More code does **explain nothing**.

Comment: Please check the implementation code. it will replace all occurrence of passed char or charSequence. I am not getting you what you are saying dude.

Comment: @NisargSanghavi The goal is to explain **WHY** you are doing, what you are doing. Just saying "Do that" as an answer will not be of great help, especially if you want to learn what the problem is, instead of just solving it. Next time you answer a question, _explain the steps you took and why you took them_. You can still edit that in this answer. What _Jägermeister_ was trying to say is that just adding more code will not serve as a better explanation. Even if you add more code, you still have to explain **why** you are doing what. Hope you understand it. - Cheers

Comment: As per my knowledge replaceAll acceps only regex string which will take more time to compile target string compared to replace() function..

Comment: Some more explaination : Pattern.compile() function in both function take different time to compile as replace() function gives input to compile() function as CharSequence and replaceAll() function gives input to compile() function as regex string which will take more time to compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int y = 0; y < possibleAnswers.length; y++) {
        display = possibleAnswers[y].replace("$", "");
        System.out.println(display);
    }
```

As suggested, I used replace method instead of replaceAll and it did the job. At the same time I learned to look at documentation for deeper understanding of such methods.

Thanks for all the help guys, truly appreciated.